# How do I make interactive notifications in iOS 8 app?

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications, push-notification, ios8

In iOS 8, there is a new feature to notifications where you can slide down on it and do an action. For example, when you get a message from iMessage and slide down on the notification, you can type in a quick response.

I've been looking through docs on how to do this, but I couldn't find it. Does anyone know where I can find out how to do it this/ where it is in docs?

Comment: Looks like you can't in iOS 8, but you can in iOS 9:  http://fancypixel.github.io/blog/2015/06/11/ios9-notifications-and-text-input/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html

for details on widgets on the notification center as well as

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIMutableUserNotificationCategory_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014610

where UIMutableUserNotification is what you're looking for.

Note that this documentation is pre-release so it can be changed whenever production is pushed.

Comment: it doesn't seems to me that quick reply is allowed, just button actions

Answer (score 3):

**Note** :- This is Step 1

```
NSString * const NotificationCategoryIdent  = @"ACTIONABLE";
NSString * const NotificationActionOneIdent = @"ACTION_ONE";
NSString * const NotificationActionTwoIdent = @"ACTION_TWO";

- (void)registerForNotification {

UIMutableUserNotificationAction *action1;
action1 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
[action1 setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
[action1 setTitle:@"Action 1"];
[action1 setIdentifier:NotificationActionOneIdent];
[action1 setDestructive:NO];
[action1 setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

UIMutableUserNotificationAction *action2;
action2 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
[action2 setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
[action2 setTitle:@"Action 2"];
[action2 setIdentifier:NotificationActionTwoIdent];
[action2 setDestructive:NO];
[action2 setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *actionCategory;
actionCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
[actionCategory setIdentifier:NotificationCategoryIdent];
[actionCategory setActions:@[action1, action2] 
                forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObject:actionCategory];
UIUserNotificationType types = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|
                                UIUserNotificationTypeSound|
                                UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);

UIUserNotificationSettings *settings;
settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types
                                             categories:categories];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
}
```

**Note** :- This is Step 2

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {

if ([identifier isEqualToString:NotificationActionOneIdent]) {

    NSLog(@"You chose action 1.");
}
else if ([identifier isEqualToString:NotificationActionTwoIdent]) {   

    NSLog(@"You chose action 2.");
}    
if (completionHandler) {

    completionHandler();
}
}
```

**Note** :- If you want to learn more, Visit this link.
https://nrj.io/simple-interactive-notifications-in-ios-8/

Answer (score -1):

I take no credit for this answer, I just found it online but it was very useful in helping my understanding of iOS8 Interactive Notifications:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/iOS_Interactive_Notifications-section-40930452_iOSInteractiveNotifications-CreateaNotificationAction