# Custom push notification screen

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, apple-push-notifications

I'm developing an iOS video chat application. I would like to display a notification like the FaceTime application does when someone calls me.

Currently I use push notifications that show banners, with a message and a custom sound.

Instead I want my app to show a custom screen for an incoming event like someone calling me for example. Is that possible using apple public API's ?

Please, see the FaceTime notification screen below.

Ps.: Skype also uses a different notification screen.

Thanks a lot,
Daniel

[image: facetime screen]

Comment: You are looking for "Today Extension" aka Widgets. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html

Comment: I don't want this screen to appear in the "Today" screen. I want it to appear when my app generates some server side event. It should appear in substitution to the traditional push notification screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt it has anything to do with push notifications, in fact Skype you are mentioning was able to do it before push notifications were available.

Instead iOS gives you some extra features if you create an app with background mode "voip" (voice over ip). This will allow the app to wake up and brought to the foreground once traffic is detected on the network sockets, and `applicationWillEnterForeground:` is called. And from there you can use any view controller.

If you now think «hmm, my app doesn't offer voip, but I will pretend to do so to get superior notifications» — don't try it, apple will reject any app claims to be a voip app just to get endless background time.

Comment: Is there any example illustrating this ? Any incoming traffic will call "applicationWillEnterForeground" ?

Answer (score 3):

No, push notification dialog is a system dialog which cannot be customized. However FaceTime is Apple's application and they can customize it the way they want, not open to third party developers.

However you can take advantage of iOS 8.0 addition "UIMutableUserNotificationCategory" to customize the actions in the notification:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIMutableUserNotificationCategory_class/index.html

Example tutorial:
http://www.thinkandbuild.it/interactive-notifications-with-notification-actions/

Comment: Skype also uses a custom notification screen. So I think it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how they did it, but Skype managed to get a customized notification when a User receives a call both while the device is locked and while in use.

[image: Device Locked Incoming Call]

[image: In Use Incoming Call]

http://blogs.skype.com/2014/09/22/skype-5-5-for-iphone-answer-skype-calls-in-an-instant/

EDIT: Looks like IOS8 added an Interactive Notifications API. This is likely your next question: [How do I make interactive notifications in iOS 8 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693608/how-do-i-make-interactive-notifications-in-ios-8-app)

Comment: Yes. So there must be some way to customize this screen. But I could not find any references in apple official documentation.

Comment: You can customize it with limited functionality supported by iOS 8.0. But not as FaceTime app. Skype uses: http://www.thinkandbuild.it/interactive-notifications-with-notification-actions/