# Adding Text Field To UILocalNotification In Swift

Tags: ios, swift

i'm a new iOS developer with swift. i have a UILocalNotification And i need to add a text field to that . for example some apps like Messages in iOS when sending notification you can drag that notification to down and answer to that Notification. in swift, how can i add a text field ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make interactive notifications in iOS 8 app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693608/how-do-i-make-interactive-notifications-in-ios-8-app)

Comment: what you want are _interactive notifications_. it's a feature that is available since iOS 8.

Comment: UIMutableUserNotification is the name of the class to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my code i added UIlocalNotifications(fireDate) in UITextField.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.alertAction = "Testing notifications on iOS8"
    localNotification.alertBody = "Date and Time"
    localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 30)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)


    var myTextField: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 100, width:310.00, height: 40.00));
    myTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1
    self.view.addSubview(myTextField)

    // convert to string
    var date = NSString(format:"%@ ", localNotification.fireDate!) as String

    // add to textfield
    myTextField.text = date
}
```

I hope you looking for this one.

Thanks